# what does reshape`(1, 1, 28, 28)` mean

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, alignment, conv-neural-network, reshape

I'm trying to reproduce the results of this code:
https://github.com/vjayd/Image-Alignment-using-CNN
the first problem I've faced is that, as far as I know, MNIST data are gray images and not color images
so why he converted them to grayscale images using rgb2gray function

```
for img_train in glob.glob(trdata):
    n = io.imread(img_train)
    n = rgb2gray(n)
    n= resize(n,(28,28))
    train_x.append(n.reshape(1, 28, 28))
```

and what does `(1, 1, 28, 28)` mean in this line

```
test_x = test_x.reshape(1, 1, 28, 28)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Pytorch model mostly requires the first dimension of the input to be the batch size. So the shape of the image is (1, 28, 28). If you want to feed only one image to the model you still have to specify the batch size, which is of course 1 for one image. Therefore he adds the batch size dimension to the image by "reshaping" it to (1, 1, 28, 28).

Comment: thank you Mr;  I couldn't not find any source where I can get MNIST data in jpg or png format. They're only available as idx3-ubyte files. I couldn't get the data to run the code correctly any help

Comment: I found the solution :https://medium.com/swlh/image-classifcation-with-google-colab-183e95bfc439